# How can I make my app switch pages when dragging page left or right with jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to make an app similar to the Facebook or Twitter android apps, and I want to make an app that has the link tabs in the top and when I either tap on the tabs or I drag a page from the edge of the screen I can load the next or previous screen (I'm not talking about swipe event, i'm looking for a drag event, identical to the behavior of the facebook and twitter android apps). Can somebody please point me to some tutorial, or the function name of the event i'm looking for? i'm using jquery mobile and html5 to build said application.

Comment: Look at touchStart, touchMove, and touchEnd. With those functions you can calculate direction and distance and work off that.